# Python ctypes can't find dependent library

Tags: python, macos, ipython, ctypes

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to load dependent libraries using ctypes in python 3.4 (in ipython) on OSX. I'm trying to load `libps3000a.dylib`, which depends on `libpicoipp.1.dylib`:

```
import os

print(os.path.exists("/Applications/PicoScope6.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libps3000a.dylib"))
print(os.path.exists("/Applications/PicoScope6.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libpicoipp.1.dylib"))

%env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH /Applications/PicoScope6.app/Contents/Resources/lib
%env LD_LIBRARY_PATH /Applications/PicoScope6.app/Contents/Resources/lib

from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("/Applications/PicoScope6.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libps3000a.dylib")
```

And the output I get is the following:

```
True
True
env: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/PicoScope6.app/Contents/Resources/lib
env: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/PicoScope6.app/Contents/Resources/lib
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-df3a8f6477f6> in <module>()
      8 
      9 from ctypes import cdll
---> 10 lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("/Applications/PicoScope6.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libps3000a.dylib")

/Users/jeremy/anaconda/lib/python3.4/ctypes/__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    427 
    428     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 429         return self._dlltype(name)
    430 
    431 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

/Users/jeremy/anaconda/lib/python3.4/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    349 
    350         if handle is None:
--> 351             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    352         else:
    353             self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(/Applications/PicoScope6.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libps3000a.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: libpicoipp.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/PicoScope6.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libps3000a.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I have found the solution. The %env directive in ipython doesn't affect the dlopen call if you are running inside an ipython kernel. I will file a bug report.

Comment: I don't have experience with OS X, but typically the loader in Unix systems caches the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at process startup. Thus using this environment variable requires a wrapper shell script to pre-set the value. Alternatively, if you're building the library yourself, you can include an `RPATH` that dynamically extends the search path at runtime.